# Dropdown closes immediately

Tags: javascript

I want my dropdown to close after each click outside itself and the input field. But after click, the field instantly opens and closes. Here's the code. It's very bulky, but it's possible to understand.

```js
var slitems = document.getElementsByClassName('slit');
  ddown = document.getElementsByClassName('ddown');
 function valueChange(n){
  var slitemsin = document.getElementsByClassName('s'+(n+1));
  for(var j=0;j<slitems.length;j++){
   slitemsin[j].addEventListener('click', function(){
    ddown[n].value = this.textContent || this.innerText;
    document.getElementById('sl'+(n+1)).classList.remove('slactive');
   });}}
 function ddownEvent(n){
  return function(){
   document.getElementById('sl'+(n+1)).classList.add('slactive');
   ddown[n].classList.remove('req');
   ddown[n].classList.add('filled');
   valueChange(n);
   };
  };
 function ex(e,n){
  return function(){
   if(e.target != ddown[n] && e.target.id != 'sl'+(n+1)){
    if(ddown[n].value === 'day' || ddown[n].value === 'month' || ddown[n].value === 'capacity' || ddown[n].value === 'year' || ddown[n].value === "hh" || ddown[n].value === 'mm') ddown[n].classList.remove('filled');
    document.getElementById('sl'+(n+1)).classList.remove('slactive');
   }
  };
 }
 for(var n=0; n<ddown.length; n++) {
  ddown[n].addEventListener('mousedown',ddownEvent(n));
  ddown[n].addEventListener('mouseup', ex(event,n));
  }
```

```css
html {
  background: black;
}
body {
 background: black;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 height: 100vh;
}
.frow {
 width: 1500px;
 height: 40px;
 border-left: 6px white solid;
 margin-top: 25px;
}
.frow:first-child{
 margin-top:60px;
}
.ptext {
 font-family: "Helvetica";
 font-size: 22px;
 background: none;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 3px #525252 solid;
 color: #525252;
 transition: all .1s;
 margin-left: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 resize:none;
 padding: 0;
}
.filled {
 color: white;
 border-bottom: 3px white solid;
}
.ptext:focus{
 color: white;
 border-bottom: 3px white solid;
}
.ptext:first-child {
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.ddown {
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
}
.sl{
 position: absolute;
 height: 0px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px black;
 overflow: auto;
 cursor: pointer;
 visibility: hidden;
 transition: all .15s;
 background-color: white;
}
.sl::-webkit-scrollbar{
 display:none;
}
.slit {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Helvetica";
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #292929;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
}
.slit:hover{
 background-color: #525252;
 color: white;
}
.slactive{
 height: 220px;
 visibility: visible;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 34px 0px black;
}
```

```html
        <div class="frow">
                <input name="Day" spellcheck="false" class="ptext ptextc ddown" type="text" value="day" minlength="1" maxlength="2" style="height:30px;width:50px;" readonly/>
                <ul class="sl" id="sl1" style="width:50px;left:15px;top:90px;">
                        <li class="slit s1">1</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">2</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">3</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">4</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">5</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">6</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">7</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">8</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">9</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">10</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">11</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">12</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">13</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">14</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">15</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">16</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">17</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">18</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">19</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">20</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">21</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">22</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">23</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">24</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">25</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">26</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">27</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">28</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">29</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">30</li>
                        <li class="slit s1">31</li>
                    </ul>
```

`ddown[n]` is an input field, sl1, sl2, sl3, ..., `'sl'+(n+1)` are dropdown IDs.

Comment: post yout html & css code also

Comment: if you could use the built-in code runner, that would help as well.

Comment: Are we to assume that by dropdown, you are referring to the `<select>` input in html?  It would be helpful if you could provide context to your problem with a jsfiddle or by adding the html that this affects.

Comment: @Pineda, no it's an unordered list with list items in it.

Comment: Will update the question in 30 minutes.

Comment: @Pineda Here it is.

Comment: Where is the dropdown element?  There isn't a `<select>` tag anywhere.  I you using some sort of javascript widget?

Comment: @Pineda I've written my own dropdown. Have you seen the snippet?

Comment: I see.  Rather than using the mouseup event, have you tried using the blur event which fires when an element loses focus?

Comment: @Pineda The blur event fires when when you leave the input element. This prevents you from selecting elements in the dropdown as you close it before it is chosen. To work correctly, this should focus dropdown too.

Comment: Ahaw... Could you not bind the ex method to the body element (rather than on the input and li elements) and run your check on targets within that?

Comment: @Pineda what do you mean by 'not binding the ex method to the body element'? I'm new to this, what exactly should I do?

Comment: that was a typo, I was suggesting binding the ex method o the click event of the body rather than what you've done and bound it to the input and the li elements.  For someone who is 'new to this' why didn't you just create a regular html dropdown with a `<select>` box?

Comment: @Pineda Binding it to the body won't even let you open the dropdown, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach event to mouseup instead. Looks like mousedown event fires first and interferes with click event handler.